# $f(x)=x^{1/3}(4-x)$ find $\lim_{ x\to +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{ x\to -\infty} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the function $$f(x)=x^{\frac13}\left(4-x\right)$$

a) What is $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ ?

b) What is $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ ?

I don't know which method I should use. calculating directly or use some other theorems?

Comment: Please format your title...

Comment: One may write $x^{1/3}(4-x)=x^{4/3}(-1+4/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}4x^{1/3}-x^{4/3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}-x^{4/3}=-\infty
$$
as the $x^{4/3}$ term dominates. Apply the same logic accounting for sign for part b.

Answer (score 0):

you can use L'Hopital's rule. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty} x^{\frac13}(4-x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{4-x}{x^{-\frac13}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{-1}{-\frac13x^{-\frac43}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}3x^{\frac43}=+\infty$$